# what has happened to get the error in laravel while I set it up

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I've gone through the steps in the [laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation) documentation. Everything is downloaded and setup.

I then innput:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

into Ubuntu. All went well and it loads and finishes. I then put entered:

```
cd example-app
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
⠿ laravel.test Error                                                                                              3.0s
[+] Building 51.4s (9/16)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:21.04                                                    1.2s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 99B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:21.04@sha256:cc6f342e3aad515ae49ec9355d852bbba50c3d63e57786438ec36d8989  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/11] WORKDIR /var/www/html                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/11] RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime && echo UTC > /etc/timezone                  0.0s
 **=> ERROR [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git sup  50.2s**
```

There are more lines (500 or so) but that's the main error.

Any advice as to what may be wrong? I can't find anything on the error and everything is updated.

these are the lines that it failed (couldnt add it to the comments)

```
#8 49.88 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/shared-mime-info/shared-mime-info_2.0-1_amd64.deb  Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
#8 49.88 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/cpp_10.3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
#8 49.88 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/gcc_10.3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  0  [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
#8 49.88 E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.0/php8.0-dev_8.0.11-1%2bubuntu21.04.1%2bdeb.sury.org%2b1_amd64.deb  Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
#8 49.88 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev        php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd        php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached        php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring        php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap        php8.0-intl php8.0-readline php8.0-pcov        php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap        php8.0-redis php8.0-swoole php8.0-xdebug     && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*]: exit code: 100
```

Comment: Please include errors as text, not images.

Comment: Presumably one of the commands in the `ERROR` line failed, I expect you have logs to check to see what happened?

Comment: added them to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1):

So just to come back to this , as I assume other poeple will have the same issue.
For me I'm not sure what the real problem was, however, I found that starting a new Laravel project with docker I need to use a VPN on the first "sail up". Once the first launch is done it will work without no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a connection issue i think. It seems to be a connection problem.

Comment: well its gotten stuck at that point muitple times and on previous days so dont think its my connection

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am not sure the below steps would work for you, but they worked out for me. I think I read somewhere that this error comes when your container has run out of memory.

- Restart the PC.
- Open Microsoft Store > Directly Open Ubuntu. No need to start docker first.
- And go to project directory and hit "sail up"

This is how it worked for me.